# How to remove countries for elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have a list which contains names of different companies and I want to remove all the names of countries from the elements in this list. I'm using pycountry to import a list of countries.

```
comps = ['XGLOW Japan', 'GOGO China', 'DALO germany', 'XTTTIndia']


countries_list = []
for p in pycountry.countries:
    p = p.name.lower()
    countries_list.append(p)


remove_countries = [i for e in countries_list for i in comps if e in i]
```

This gets me the list of companies that contain country names but now I'm not entirely sure how to remove them.

This is an example of how to do it for a single element.

```
example = 'DoNow China'.lower()

for p in pycountry.countries:
    if p.name.lower() in example:
        print(example.replace(p.name.lower(), '')) # gives me "donow"
```

Desired Output:

```
comps
['XGLOW', 'GOGO', 'DALO', 'XTTT']
```

Comment: Do you care about preserving upper and lowercases in company names?

Comment: no its not important

Comment: How did you end up in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re
import pycountry

# create a pattern that will match any country in pycountry.countries
names = '|'.join([country.name for country in pycountry.countries])
pattern = re.compile(names, re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE)

companies = ['XGLOW Japan', 'GOGO China', 'DALO germany', 'XTTTIndia']

# apply sub for each company
result = [pattern.sub("", company).strip() for company in companies]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['XGLOW', 'GOGO', 'DALO', 'XTTT']
```

This approach will keep the case of the strings.

Answer (score 1):

You were quite close! Preserving your logic, you could find every value like this:}

```
comps = ['XGLOW Japan', 'GOGO China', 'DALO germany', 'XTTTIndia']
comps = [c.lower() for c in comps]
countries = ['japan', 'china', 'germany', 'india'] #Didn't want to install pycountries
for p in countries:
    for c in comps:
        if p.lower() in c:
            print(c.replace(p.lower(),''))
```

Which in list comprehension format is:

```
 [c.replace(p.lower(),'') for p in countries for c in comps if p.lower() in c]
```

I'm not sure how `pycountry` works but if you're having troubles going from my list of countries to pycountry's countries, let me know and I'll help you.

Output:

```
Out: ['xglow ', 'gogo ', 'dalo ', 'xttt']
```